# KDE Plasma vs FCITX: What component is swallowing Ctrl-5?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, plasma, fcitx

After enabling Pinyin input via FCITX in KDE Plasma (Ubuntu Studio 22.04), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> gets eaten by something but I can't find where it is set, to change it.

In Settings > Shortcuts, you can search for the name of the command, but not for the key combo.

I see "Shortcuts are recorded" in `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc` and `~/.config/khotkeysrc`, but `Ctrl+5` is absent from both of these files.

On a lark I grepped all the files in `~/.config/fcitx` for `Ctrl+5`, but no matches.

Does anyone know where this is?

hjh

Comment: What is `Ctrl+5` supposed to do? There is not such a global shortcut. Is it an application specific shortcut?

Comment: I actually don't know what ctrl+5 is doing *in the system*. But something is blocking it. I need it as an application-specific keybinding in Pure Data audio software, but it isn't working there. It must be something in the system but it is unsearchable.